# Haskell compare issue

Tags: haskell

I use recursion to compare two numbers(ex 123 is the same with 123) and store how many digits they have in common(ex 123 compared to 123 has 3 and with 124 has 2).

While my program does find that number i want to put conditions for every situation (ex if they have 2 digits in common output value 44 or if they have 3 do something else etc.) but no comparison is done. Can someone please explain to me what and why that happens. Here my code :

```
dg :: Int->Int->Int  
dg 0 0 = 0
dg x y = if (c==2) then 23 else 24 -- c = common digits
    where c = digits (x `div` 10) (y `div` 10) + if (x `mod` 10 == y `mod` 10) then 1 else 0
```

I run hugs deleting the "if" condition, giving input 10 10 the output is 2 but when i leave it on and rerun it, it goes to 24 (while 23 is correct). I'm really confused.

Comment: I would turn both numbers into `[Char]` and then happily compared the lists, smth like `common l1 l2 = [e1 | e1 <- l1, elem e1 l2]`, though it has O(n^2) performance. Comparing the lists is especially efficient if you only care about the set of the common elements and not the order; you can sort the both lists.

Comment: What's `digits`? And why are you using hugs?

Answer (score 1):

To find how many digits two `Int` have in common, using the string representation <strike>isn't too bad</strike> (It's actually terrible, **see update below**).

```hs
commonDigits :: Int -> Int -> Int
commonDigits a b = length . filter id $ zipWith (==) (reverse $ show a) (reverse $ show b)
```

`reverse` is needed to make sure the digits align properly.

If you're into point-free style:

```hs
import Data.Function

commonDigits :: Int -> Int -> Int
commonDigits = fmap (length . filter id) . zipWith (==) `on` reverse . show
```

Then if you want to return a special `Int` depending on the result of `commonDigits` you can use a separate function:

```hs
specialResult :: Int -> Int -> Int
specialResult a b =
  case commonDigits a b of
    2 -> 23
    3 -> 48
    _ -> 256
```

**Update**: For negative integers this method is not good. If only one of the argument is negative this function should behave like your *mod 10* version. If both are negative there is the possibility that the '-' sign is counted as a digit.

Let's use a `digits` function that will give a list of digits for both positive and negative numbers from the least significant to the most significant digits. What happens if the number `0` is given as input, should we return an empty list or `[0]`? Your call on that one, but I'm going to assume you want `[0]`.

```hs
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits 0 = [0]
digits n = digits' (abs n)
  where
    digits' 0 = []
    digits' n = n `mod` 10 : digits' (n `div` 10)
```

With this new `digits` function we can rewrite `commonDigits` to:

```hs
commonDigits :: Int -> Int -> Int
commonDigits = fmap (length . filter id) . zipWith (==) `on` digits
```